# Error using esapi with CF8 and JavaLoader

Tags: java, coldfusion, javaloader, esapi

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException SecurityConfiguration class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration) CTOR threw exception.
```

I get the above error when I try to do

```
    <cfset esapi=JavaLoader.create('org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI')/>
    <cfdump var="#esapi.randomizer()#"/>
```

So I'm guessing that I haven't done some setup step for the esapi.. but I"m not sure what..

Comment: oops can someone please migrate this to stackoverflow?

Comment: I do not have answer, but can you post more of the stack trace? It would help others in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: here is the stack trace http://pastebin.com/1hRxdHsw

Comment: I am not familiar with this library. But the error message is saying it the configuration file ie `ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means`. Total shot in the dark, but you might review this thread on configuration file location. Maybe you could place it inside the jar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696423/trying-to-use-esapi-but-getting-error/7697740#7697740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is saying it cannot find the configuration file ie `ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means`. Total shot in the dark, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696423/trying-to-use-esapi-but-getting-error/7697740#7697740) suggests it will be detected if you place it inside the jar within the resources folder ie

```
   /resources/ESAPI.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the esapi jar to your CF server classpath?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of using the javaLoader ;)