# Errors while configuring ESAPI

Tags: java, security

I see errors when I run the test code from ESAPI documentation.

```
    import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;

public class EsapiTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("ESAPI.accessController found: " 
                               + ESAPI.accessController());
    }
}
```

This is the error I get -

```
Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
    ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means. Fail. Exception was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
    Exception in thread "main" org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException SecurityConfiguration class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration) CTOR threw exception.
        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
        at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.securityConfiguration(ESAPI.java:184)
        at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.accessController(ESAPI.java:85)
        at tools.EsapiIntegrationTest.main(EsapiIntegrationTest.java:3)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: ESAPI.properties could not be loaded by any means. Fail.
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:439)
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.<init>(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:227)
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.getInstance(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:75)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfigurationFromClasspath(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:667)
        at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.loadConfiguration(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:436)
        ... 10 more
```

I have no clue what I am missing here. As suggested here - [Trying to Use ESAPI But getting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696423/trying-to-use-esapi-but-getting-error), I put the properties in org/owasp/esapi/resources, bundled it up, and put the jar in my classpath, but no luck. I also tried passing arguments in eclipse - -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="/Users/rick/Desktop/test/myworkspace" (this folder has the property files) The documentation is just so poor that I am completely lost. Please help what am I missing here? Any link that has all the steps to do the setup?

Comment: the link also says to try putting the properties files together with the jar file in the resource folder.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Still no luck :(

Comment: try to run from command prompt. http://lists.owasp.org/pipermail/esapi-user/2012-June/000986.html